# Font album of Umberto Tozzi: Notte Rosa 1981 and 2024

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing

With much sadness my favorite world-known singer *Umberto Tozzi* (I remember: "Gloria", "Ti amo"...) have announced his retirement from live concerts from half 2025.

[image: data:image/jpeg;base64,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]

If we look at the characters of 'Notte Rosa' from 1981 and 2024, we see that there are many similarities, but they are not perfectly identical.

[image: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.friendsandpartners.it%2Fres%2Fimages%2Ftours%2F20240315_144905_GzRL9O8GH1bwcnZjGneNto1lYca2bedO9wGUZX2R.jpg&tbnid=1ErxZOZ1dsa0nM&vet=12ahUKEwjgmqnmiveEAxXqif0HHTafDawQMygBegQIARA8..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.friendsandpartners.it%2Fin-tour%2Fumberto-tozzi-lultima-notte-rosa-the-final-tour&docid=19K-plL8qHiS8M&w=1920&h=1080&itg=1&q=notte%20rosa%20tozzi&hl=it&ved=2ahUKEwjgmqnmiveEAxXqif0HHTafDawQMygBegQIARA8]

I don't think there were typographic characters in 1981 (or peraphs exist a similar font) and I wouldn't know how they made up those characters. I ask myself this question:

> by what current technique have the original characters of the 1981 'Notte Rosa' inscription been modified to look very similar to those of 2024?

Comment: Hi Sebastiano. Welcome to GDSE. Yes there were fonts in the 1980's. However, it might not have been a font originally. Sometimes graphic designers create lettering by hand - especially for logos. Even today, some still create custom lettering by hand. Also, computer fonts today are generally still drawn by hand - but using font creation software such as fontforge, or fontlab. It's possible to digitise an old design to make it into a modern computer font. They're drawn using vectors.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi Bill. Thank you very much for your new welcome. I not write here much. For me, it would be interesting to understand the technique of how they went from a hand-created font to a vector font almost similar to the original. Thanks always.

Comment: Sorry Sebastiano, I thought you were a brand new contributor. No worries though.  You would use font creation software, or just vector software.  [See an example](https://imgur.com/8Y52mX3). I drew this very quickly using Inkscape, which is a vector image editor which is free.  I used your example image to trace over the top of it as a guide.

Comment: @BillyKerr Fantastic. I guess you got the first one written. But could everything be converted into LaTeX/TikZ code?

Comment: I don't have any experience with these,  so I don't know.  Sorry. Vector software and font software uses Bézier curves to create shapes like this.  The tool is sometimes called a Pen tool/Bézier tool.  If your software can import SVGs, then yes - these are vector. If you add the vectors to a real font, using font creation software, then I'm pretty sure almost any software could use them.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi, can you put an answer looking also the fill of the curves? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you mean you want to create an outline font, you would do that by converting a stroke to a path with a fill. This can be done in vector image editing software such as Inkscape/Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: @BillyKerr I am curious of see the answer that I will vote surely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I can answer this now. It seems you want to know how to re-create letters of a font, from a raster image, and then create outlines so that you can use them to create a font to use in other software.

I am going to use Inkscape here, which is a free and open source vector image editor, but the same thing could be done using Adobe Illustrator, or other similar vector editors. What follows isn't a tutorial, just the basic steps.  You can find good tutorials on youtube that teach how to use this tool.

The first step is to trace the letter forms manually, using the Pen Tool (aka Bézier tool). You can use the image as a guide to make the letters. Some guides will also help you get everything straight and lined up

[image]

From here, one can apply a thicker stroke to a letter and then convert the stroke to a path, leaving an outline path which is filled. In Inkscape this is done by using Path > Stroke to Path (the equivalent in Adobe Illustrator is Object > Expand).

[image]

This can then be directly pasted into a glyph in font creation software such as FontForge (also free and open source). Obviously creating a font is quite time consuming, since the letters are drawn manually.

Here's an example of pasting the Inkscape outlines into the Capital N glyph in FontForge.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful wonderful+1